# applescript - control click

Tags: macos, user-interface, user-controls, applescript, controls

How can I control click with AppleScript?

This script should work, but it doesn't

```
activate application "Finder"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        key down control
        delay 1
        click at {600, 600} -- {from left, from top}
        delay 1
        key up control
    end tell
end tell
```

MouseTools is sometimes unreliable. I know of cliclick — still haven't tried it.

I'd prefer an AS only workaround but welcome any suggestions.

Comment: I assume you're trying to open the context menu of a particular file or folder in finder.  Once you have that menu open, which menu item do you intend clicking on?

Comment: @AtomicToothbrush Once CM is open I just `keystroke "My Command" & return`

Answer (score 0):

- Most of the actions from contextual menu you can do using menu bar (File, Edit, etc.). It can simplify your job.
- To open contextual menu for particular GUI element you should tell to `perform action 
  "AXShowMenu"` to that element. You can use Accessibility Inspector application to find out the GUI elements hierarchy. Take a look at [this discussion](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=14300).
- You can try mouse keys. Take a look at [this](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-103714.html) thread for details. Note that "Mouse Keys" settings is in the "System Preferences" -> "Accessibility" -> "Mouse & Trackpad" in Mountain Lion.
- For finder scripting [AppleScript Finder Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/AppleScriptFinderGuide.pdf) can be of much help.

Comment: Thanks, but none of those options are new to me. I'm trying to _not just_ make the context menu show, but do it via control clicking with AppleScript.